# How to set up bluetooth broadcasting on a pi 3 b v1.2

Tags: python, pi-3b+, bluetooth, bluez

um new to working with bluetooth on linux or on a raspberry pi but i have managed to set up the controllers.
What i want to accomplish now is using python to connect or broadcast my raspberry pi as a server where multiple devices can send data to my pi and vise versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux there is support for Bluetooth serial connections using the standard Python installation.

Python Docs:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html

There is a blog with more detail:

http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

And the [Blue Dot](https://pypi.org/project/bluedot/) library has abstracted it to be slightly easier to use:

https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html